# Разделить байт на полубайты и по двум полубайтам получить байт

Tags: c, struct, enum

Не могу добиться нужной работы от структуры в enum. Мне нужно из двух полубайт (тетрад) получать байт в подобной структуре. Для компактной записи у меня в одной тетраде длина (0-F) а во второй длина индексов 0-F (алгоритм LZ78). Получая значения к примеру 0х08 и 0х0F мне нужно чтобы в структуре оно объединялось в байт, который можно прочитать как 0x8F. Помогите написать структуру правильно :) Я где-то рядом с решением.
Добавил пояснения к коду.

```
struct BYTE{
    unsigned char L:4; //Где-то в примерах unsigned L:4;
    unsigned char H:4; //Но не работает всё равно :(
};
union Byte{
    unsigned char byte;
    struct BYTE LH;
};

union Byte DILen;

unsigned char D[16];//Словарь символов из строки
unsigned char I[16];//Индексы ссылки на символы словаря
unsigned char DC,IC;//Счетчики словаря и индексов, для подсчета их кол-ва

int main(){
    
    DC = 0x09;//В словаре 9 символов
    IC = 0x0F;//И 15 индексов, ссылок на символы в словаре

    DILen.LH.L = DC;//DC это байт от 0 до F (0F max)
    DILen.LH.H = IC;//IC от 0 до F (0F max)
    
    //D[0] для хранения тетрадой размера словаря и кол-ва индексов (9F)
    D[0] = DILen.byte;//В итоге D[0]=0x09 , вместо 0x9F при значениях DC=0x09 IC=0x0F 

}
```

```
Вывод программы упаковки по алгоритму LZ78
Str: 'КРАСНАЯ КРАСКА 1' len: 16.
Print Dic&Indx. В D[0] индекс записывать длину словаря F-0 и индексов 0-F
D[0] =   I[0] = 0
D[1] = К I[1] = 0
D[2] = Р I[2] = 0
D[3] = А I[3] = 0
D[4] = С I[4] = 0
D[5] = Н I[5] = 3
D[6] = Я I[6] = 0
D[7] =   I[7] = 0
D[8] = 1 I[8] = 1
D[9] =   I[9] = 2
D[10] =   I[10] = 3
D[11] =   I[11] = 4
D[12] =   I[12] = 1
D[13] =   I[13] = 3
D[14] =   I[14] = 7
D[15] =   I[15] = 0

DicCount 8[08] IndexCount 15[0F] DILen [09]!Это тетрада DC:IC
При распаковке читаем D[0]=длина словаря F0 длина индексов 0F(полубайты)
Если индекс =0 увел. индекс словаря, иначе символ по инднксу
```

Comment: Используйте просто `unsigned char byte;` и соотв. сеттеры и геттеры. Объединения и структуры с битовыми полями не нужны.

Comment: @user7860670 Я пробовал :) И "пришел" именно к такой системе записи.  Это лишь часть, большого алгоритма. И мне так проще распихивать битики и байтики, чтобы не запутаться и более наглядно ;)
А сеттеры и геттеры это к Си++ ООП по моему относится? Мне Си подходит ;)

Comment: Нет, и сеттеры, и геттеры, и ООП вполне себе относятся и к С. И они как раз помогут не запутываться.

Comment: А сдвигом что не делается?

Comment: @eri Типа сдвинуть DC<<4 и сложить с IC? Работает. Но вот прочитал про такие enum структуры, понравился подход и простота :) И где-то я рядом с правильной работой этого метода, но какая-то маленькая деталь, не дает ему правильно работать. И кто-то знает какая :)

Comment: Мне кажется они только на чтение...

Comment: @eri Ну 09 туда записывается ;) В полубайт. У меня есть набор функций работы с битами, я могу и ими это реализовать, но так мне понятнее и проще будет. чем куча setbit(var,pos).

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы sizeof(Byte) был  равен 1, то в struct BYTE используйте unsigned char поля (у вас сейчас просто unsigned, а это 4-х байтовый unsigned int). Если хотите получить из DC = 0x09; IC = 0x0F; `0x9F`, то переставьте присваивания местами (сейчас у вас должно получаться 0xF9 (младшие 4 бита это L, естественно, они печатаются справа)). Почему у вас D[0] == 0x09 не знаю, наверное какая-то ошибка при печати, в общем, приведите полный код, если сами не можете найти

Comment: @avp Благодарю, попробую исправить. Я заметил еще то, что присваивания к 4 битам происходит странное. И вывести в printf я не могу полубайт (тетраду), ошибка при компиляции. Из схем приведенных в инете, написано что для полубайтов используйте unsigned (не char). Потому так и осталос, хотя менялось на char, но к результатом не приводило.

Comment: @avp По поводу кода. Там код упаковки методом LZ78. Он выдает массив D[16] словарь, I[16] индекс символа в массиве D[]. DC это счетчик символов в словаре (Dict Count) а IC счетчик индексов.
В примере упаковки LZ78 написано что индексы I[16] нужно записать тетрадами, для экономии. А в D[0] поместит DC:IC тетрадой, чтобы знать размер словаря и кол-во индексов. Ну и в конце кода я провожу "испытания" как работать с тетрадами. И то что я привел, это и есть часть для полубайт.

Comment: `так проще распихивать битики и байтики, чтобы не запутаться и более наглядно ... Не могу добиться нужной работы`. Ясно :) Битовые поля сильно implementation-defined. По стандарту в `D[0]` можно получить и `0xF9`, и `0x9F`. Вариант со сдвигами выглядит надёжней. Не удивлюсь, если можно придумать заковыристую реализацию, которая выдаст даже `0x09`, хотя на практике такое значение выглядит неправдоподобно. Нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Пока [не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/6Td8qqroE).

Comment: @wololo Привет. Так у вас вывелось! F9. И правильно. printf("\nDicLen %u[%.2X] Indx len %u[%.2X] DILen [%.2X]\n",DC-1,DC-1,IC-1,IC-1,DILen.byte); Разница в параметре вывода printf? У вас (unsigned)D[0]. Неужели в этом ошибка? Сейчас проверю =) Неа! у меня 09 выводит :( В чем же тогда проблема? Если у вас выводит правильно а у меня нет? :(

Comment: @wololo Спасибо! Нашел ошибку! Оказывается индекс IC у меня 0х10 (16) а не 0х0F (15). Там в цикле счетчик увеличился под следующее значение, а 0F это конец был. И в строке DILen.LH.H = IC; он не 0F присваивал как я думал а 0х10 в тетраду! Потому и 0х09 получалось. Так что всё работает, буду завтра новые баги писать ;)